# Efficient way to pad a dimension with values from another array

Tags: numpy

Say I want to pad a numpy array, to make room for an extra column of values in one of the dimensions:

```
>>> cells.shape
(2, 3, 12, 4)
>>> padded = np.pad(cells, ((0,0),(0,0),(0,0),(0,1)))
>>> padded.shape
(2, 3, 12, 5)
```

If I have the values for the new column in another 1D array, what is the most efficient way to insert them into `cells`?

Comment: `padded[..., -1].ravel()[...] = arr`.  This assumes however that your array is contiguous, which it should be because `pad` will return a copy.

Comment: @user3483203 I found this way `padded[:,:,:,-1] = arr` ...which is simpler to write. Any thoughts on which is "better"?

Comment: I guess your way will work regardless of how many dimensions in my target array, so that's nice

Comment: `padded[...,-1] = arr` ...best of both :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I found with help from @user3483203 in the comments...

If we start with:

```py
>>> cells.shape
(2, 3, 12, 4)
```

And we pad that array in the last dimension to add another column:

```py
>>> padded = np.pad(cells, ((0,0),(0,0),(0,0),(0,1)))
>>> padded.shape
(2, 3, 12, 5)
```

Nicest way I found to insert values in the new column is:

```py
>>> padded[..., -1] = new_values
```